# Failed communication with server during registration in Laravel website

Tags: php, laravel, server

[here's an image of the netwrork on browser's dev tools when i try to resend the email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKh6y.png)i'm working on a project made by someone else in Laravel, it's already running and i'm just trying to fix some bugs but i have very few experience and don't know where to put my hands.

Since a few days when users try to register to the website it get stucks, doesn't go any further and doesn't send any confirmation email to the user, on console it gives me:
"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()"
But on the admin panel i see the registration and i can manually activate it.

Registration form:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="register" data-type="modal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                @lang(session('lang').'.sign_up_2')
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                    <span>&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form action="{{ url('register') }}" class="ajax_form">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                    <input type="hidden" name="front" value="1">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 top-modal bgff">
                            @lang(session('lang').'.sing_up_text') <span style="color:#3097D1;cursor:pointer;" data-target="#login" onclick="showModal($(this))">@lang(session('lang').'.sing_up_text_2')</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <label for="">@lang(session('lang').'.social_sing_up_text')</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <a href="{{ url('/register/facebook') }}" class="btn btn-facebook btn-block"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> Facebook</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <a href="{{ url('/register/google') }}" class="btn btn-google btn-block"><i class="fa fa-google"></i> Google</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 top-modal">
                            @lang(session('lang').'.sing_up_text_2')
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="">@lang(session('lang').'.name')</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="">@lang(session('lang').'.last_name')</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastname">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="">@lang(session('lang').'.phone')</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="">@lang(session('lang').'.email')</label>
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="">@lang(session('lang').'.password')</label>
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
                            <div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom: 0">
                                <label for="">@lang(session('lang').'.sex'):</label> 
                                <label><input type="radio" name="sex_ajax" value="M" checked> @lang(session('lang').'.male')</label>
                                <label><input type="radio" name="sex_ajax" value="F"> @lang(session('lang').'.female')</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <div class="text-center form-group hide" id="spinner">
                                <img src="{{ url('img/AjaxLoader.gif') }}" alt="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="alert alert-danger hide" id="error"></div>
                            <div class="alert alert-success hide" id="success">@lang(session('lang').'.success_register')</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
                            <div class="checkbox" style="margin-bottom: 20px; margin-top: 0">
                                <input type="hidden" name="modal" value="1">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="disclaimer"> @lang(session('lang').'.accept_text') <a href="{{ url('pagina/privacy') }}" target="_blank">@lang(session('lang').'.accept_text_2')</a> @lang(session('lang').'.accept_text_1')
                                </label>
                            </div>

                            <div class="checkbox" style="margin-bottom: 20px; margin-top: 0">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="accept"> @lang(session('lang').'.declaration_text')
                                </label>
                            </div>

                            

                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-gengle W-320">@lang(session('lang').'.sign_up')</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

RegisterController

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */
use RegistersUsers;

/**
 * Where to redirect users after registration.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $redirectTo = '/home';

/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest');
}

/**
 * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
 */
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
    ]);
}

/**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \App\User
 */
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

}

web.php

```
<?php


Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'FrontController@index');
    Route::get('/changeLang/{lang}', function ($lang) {
        session(['lang' => $lang]);
        return back();
    })->where([
        'lang' => 'it|fr'
    ]);
});

Route::group(['prefix' => 'steps', 'middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'StepsController@index');
    Route::post('/upload-profile-image', 'StepsController@upImageProfile');
    Route::post('/sex', 'StepsController@sexInfo');
    Route::post('/birthday', 'StepsController@birthdayInfo');
    Route::post('/address', 'StepsController@addressInfo');
    Route::post('/state-civil', 'StepsController@stateCivil');
    Route::post('/childrens', 'StepsController@childrens');
    Route::post('/delete-child', 'StepsController@deleteChild');
});


Route::get('/migrar', 'LoginController@migrar');
Route::post('load-more-news', 'FrontController@loadMoreNews');
Route::post('load-more-entry', 'FrontController@loadMoreEntry');

Route::get('diario/{id}', function($id) {
    if(!session()->has('region'/*'region_eventi'*/)){
        if(Auth::check()){
            if(Auth::user()->province != NULL){
                $p = App\Province::find(Auth::user()->province);
                $reg = App\Region::find($p->region_id);

                session(['region'/*'region_eventi'*/ => $reg->id]);
            }else{
                $reg = App\Region::first();
                session(['region'/*'region_eventi'*/ => $reg->id]);
            }
        }else{
            $reg = App\Region::first();
            session(['region'/*'region_eventi'*/ => $reg->id]);
        }
    }
    if (Auth::check()) {
        $wall = [];
        $wall[] = App\Wall::find($id);
        if (!$wall[0]) {
            return redirect('/');
        }
        return view('web.wall-single', compact('wall'));
    }
    return view('web.landing');
});

Route::get('logout', function() {
    session()->forget('region');
    session()->forget('region_name');
    Auth::logout();
    return redirect('/');
});


Route::get('login',['as' => 'login', 'uses' => function(){
    return redirect('/');
}]);

Route::post('search-user', 'BackController@searchUser');
Route::post('search-group', 'BackController@searchGroup');

Route::post('search-users', 'BackController@searchUsers');
Route::post('search-users-block', 'BackController@searchUsersBlock');
Route::post('block-user', 'BackController@blockUser');

Route::post('checkBlocked', 'FrontController@checkBlocked');

Route::post('unblock-user', 'BackController@unblockUser');
Route::post('search-region', 'BackController@searchRegion');
Route::post('search-materials', 'BackController@searchMaterials');

Route::post('searchUsersToAdd', 'BackController@searchUsersToAdd');


Route::get('/register/{provider}' , 'FrontController@getProvider');
Route::get('/register/{provider}/callback' , 'FrontController@getUserProvider');

/***/

Route::post('register', 'UsersController@store');
Route::post('login', 'UsersController@login');


    Route::get('exportUsers','UsersController@exportUsers');
    
    Route::get('login', 'LoginController@login');
    Route::post('login', 'LoginController@auth');

    Route::post('setSort', 'UsersController@setSort');
    Route::post('deleteUser', 'UsersController@deleteUser');





        Route::group(['prefix' => 'utenti'], function(){
            Route::get('/','UsersController@index');
            Route::get('/ricerca','UsersController@search');
            Route::get('/create','UsersController@create');
            Route::post('/store','UsersController@store');
            Route::get('/edit/{id}','UsersController@edit');
            Route::post('/update','UsersController@update');
        });

        
    });
});
```

Here's the log when I try click "resend the email":

```
[2021-03-31 22:09:20] local.ERROR: Swift_TransportException: Expected response code 250 but got code "550", with message "550 5.1.0 <welcome@gengle.it> utente disabilitato / account disabled
" in /var/www/vhosts/gengle.it/httpdocs/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php:383
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/vhosts/gengle.it/httpdocs/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php(281): Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->_assertResponseCode('550 5.1.0 <welc...', Array)
#1 /var/www/vhosts/gengle.it/httpdocs/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/EsmtpTransport.php(270): Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->executeCommand('MAIL FROM:<welc...', Array, Array)
#2 /var/www/vhosts/gengle.it/httpdocs/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/EsmtpTransport.php(346): Swift_Transport_EsmtpTransport->executeCommand('MAIL FROM:<welc...', Array)
#3 /var/www/vhosts/gengle.it/httpdocs/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php(416): Swift_Transport_EsmtpTransport->_doMailFromCommand('welcome@gengle....')
#4 /var/www/vhosts/gengle.it/httpdocs/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php(444): Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->_doMailTransaction(Object(Swift_Message), 'welcome@gengle....', Array, Array)
#5 /var/www/vhosts/gengle.it/httpdocs/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php(176): Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->_sendTo(Object(Swift_Message), 'welcome@gengle....', Array, Array)
#6 /var/www/vhosts/gengle.it/httpdocs/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Mailer.php(85): Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->send(Object(Swift_Message), Array)
#7 /var/www/vhosts/gengle.it/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailer.php(443): Swift_Mailer->send(Object(Swift_Message), Array)
#8 /var/www/vhosts/gengle.it/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailer.php(217): Illuminate\Mail\Mailer->sendSwiftMessage(Object(Swift_Message))
#9 /var/www/vhosts/gengle.it/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php(221): Illuminate\Mail\Mailer->send('web.confirmatio...', Array, Object(Closure))
#10 /var/www/vhosts/gengle.it/httpdocs/app/Http/Controllers/UsersController.php(442): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic('send', Array)
#11 [internal function]: App\Http\Controllers\UsersController->resend()
#12 /var/www/vhosts/gengle.it/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php(55): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#13 /var/www/vhosts/gengle.it/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(44): Illuminate\Routing\Controller->callAction('resend', Array)
#14 /var/www/vhosts/gengle.it/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(203): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(App\Http\Controllers\UsersController), 'resend')
#15 /var/www/vhosts/gengle.it/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(160): Illuminate\Routing\Route->runController()
#16 /var/www/vhosts/gengle.it/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(572): Illuminate\Routing\Route->run()
#17 /var/www/vhosts/gengle.it/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(30): Illuminate\Routing\Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#18 /var/www/vhosts/gengle.it/httpdocs/app/Http/Controllers/UsersController.php(68): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#19 /var/www/vhosts/gengle.it/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(131): App\Http\Controllers\UsersController->App\Http\Controllers\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#20 /var/www/vhosts/gengle.it/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#21 /var/www/vhosts/gengle.it/httpdocs/app/Http/Middleware/LangMiddleware.php(33): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#22 /var/www/vhosts/gengle.it/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): App\Http\Middleware\LangMiddleware->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#23 /var/www/vhosts/gengle.it/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#24 /var/www/vhosts/gengle.it/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php(41): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#25 /var/www/vhosts/gengle.it/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#26 /var/www/vhosts/gengle.it/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#27 /var/www/vhosts/gengle.it/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Middleware/Authenticate.php(43): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#28 /var/www/vhosts/gengle.it/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#29 /var/www/vhosts/gengle.it/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#30 /var/www/vhosts/gengle.it/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php(65): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#31 /var/www/vhosts/gengle.it/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#32 /var/www/vhosts/gengle.it/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#33 /var/www/vhosts/gengle.it/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php(49): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#34 /var/www/vhosts/gengle.it/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#35 /var/www/vhosts/gengle.it/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#36 /var/www/vhosts/gengle.it/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php(64): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#37 /var/www/vhosts/gengle.it/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#38 /var/www/vhosts/gengle.it/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#39 /var/www/vhosts/gengle.it/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#40 /var/www/vhosts/gengle.it/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#41 /var/www/vhosts/gengle.it/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#42 /var/www/vhosts/gengle.it/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php(59): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#43 /var/www/vhosts/gengle.it/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#44 /var/www/vhosts/gengle.it/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#45 /var/www/vhosts/gengle.it/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(102): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#46 /var/www/vhosts/gengle.it/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(574): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#47 /var/www/vhosts/gengle.it/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(533): Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#48 /var/www/vhosts/gengle.it/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(511): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#49 /var/www/vhosts/gengle.it/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(176): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#50 /var/www/vhosts/gengle.it/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(30): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#51 /var/www/vhosts/gengle.it/httpdocs/app/Http/Middleware/LangMiddleware.php(33): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#52 /var/www/vhosts/gengle.it/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): App\Http\Middleware\LangMiddleware->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#53 /var/www/vhosts/gengle.it/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#54 /var/www/vhosts/gengle.it/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(30): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#55 /var/www/vhosts/gengle.it/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#56 /var/www/vhosts/gengle.it/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#57 /var/www/vhosts/gengle.it/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(30): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#58 /var/www/vhosts/gengle.it/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#59 /var/www/vhosts/gengle.it/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#60 /var/www/vhosts/gengle.it/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#61 /var/www/vhosts/gengle.it/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#62 /var/www/vhosts/gengle.it/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#63 /var/www/vhosts/gengle.it/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(46): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#64 /var/www/vhosts/gengle.it/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#65 /var/www/vhosts/gengle.it/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#66 /var/www/vhosts/gengle.it/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(102): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#67 /var/www/vhosts/gengle.it/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(151): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#68 /var/www/vhosts/gengle.it/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(116): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#69 /var/www/vhosts/gengle.it/httpdocs/public/index.php(62): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#70 {main}
```

What can i do? What could be the problem?
What can i show you to give you more information that can be useful in order to help me?

Comment: You need to share the code as we cannot help you without seeing the code

Comment: Check the logs your logs in storage/logs/laravel.log. If you see nothing there check your web server logs /var/log/apache2 or /var/log/nginx.

Comment: `[2021-03-31 22:09:20] local.ERROR: Swift_TransportException: Expected response code 250 but got code "550", with message "550 5.1.0 <welcome@gengle.it> utente disabilitato / account disabled.`

Is sender email account active?

Comment: Thank you for your help, the laravel.log was useful, the email account has been disactivated by accident by someone